# Firing events using Symfony's EventDispatcher

Tags: php, symfony, events

I'm using Symfony's EventDispatcher component to trigger and handle events in my app, i have created a global helper function `fire(Event $event)` inside a Helpers.php file, which i autoload using composer.

Helpers.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Helpers\ConfigManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

//listeners array defined in another file.
$listeners = [
    [\App\Events\ExampleEvent::class => \App\Listeners\ExampleListener::class], 
    [\App\Events\JobEvent::class => \App\Listeners\JobEventListener::class]
];

if (!function_exists('fire')) {

    function fire(Event $event) {
        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        $listeners  = ConfigManager::getInstance()->getEventListeners();

        foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
            foreach ($listener as $ev => $handler) {
                $instance = new $handler;
                if (method_exists($instance, 'handle')) {
                    $dispatcher->addListener($ev, [$instance, 'handle']);
                }
            }
        }

        //events should be dispatched once
        //remove duplicate events name from events array.
        $events = array_unique(
                      array_map(function ($listener) {
                          return array_keys($listener)[0]; 
                      }, $listeners)
                  );

        foreach ($events as $ev) {
            if ($event instanceof $ev) {
                $dispatcher->dispatch($ev, $event);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i use it like so : `fire(new ExampleEvent('payload'));`

This function is available everywhere in my app, Each time i call it the EventListeners in the $listeners array are registered then the $event is dispatched.

The issue is, I'm not sure if this is the best way to register and dispatch events, because for every call to this function the listeners have to be registered before the event is dispatched.

Should I register the listeners somewhere else then just fire the event inside the function, any ideas?

PS. I'm not using any framework.

Comment: You should definitely not create an event dispatcher and register all listeners each time you need to fire an event.  You already have a singleton so maybe make  EventManager::registerListeners() and EventManager::fire().  But in the long run I suspect just giving you app code access to the dispatcher and letting them call dispatch is where you will end up.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the tip, where and when should i call the `EventManager::registerListeners()`, i don't have an entry point for the app (no FrontController) i don't have a way to bootstrap the app.

Comment: The fire method could call register the first time it is called.  But not having a bootstrap will probably cause other awkward work arounds as well.

Comment: i guess you're right, the code base is huge, to add functionality without breaking it is pretty hard, so i had to use the EventDispatcher, well i guess i'll create a bootstrap.php file which i will require once per file, then have my EventListeners registered there. thanks again for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no way to bootstrap the app, so all i did was create a singleton `EventManager`, with two methods `registerListeners()` and `fire(Event $event)`, then i created a bootstrap.php (work around), which i **require once** per module.

in my bootstrap.php :

```
EventManager::getInstance()->registerListeners();
```

EventManager singleton:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Helpers;


use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

class EventManager
{
    private $dispatcher = null;

    private $listeners = null;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        $this->listeners = ConfigManager::getInstance()->getEventListeners();
    }

    private function __clone() {} //nah, no clones.

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if ($instance === null) {
            $instance = new EventManager();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    public function registerListeners()
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $listener) {
            foreach ($listener as $ev => $handler) {
                $instance = new $handler;
                if (method_exists($instance, 'handle')) {
                    $this->dispatcher->addListener($ev, [$instance, 'handle']);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function fire(Event $event)
    {
        //events should be dispatched once, remove duplicate event name from events array.
        $events = array_unique(array_map(function ($listener) { return array_keys($listener)[0]; }, $this->listeners));

        foreach ($events as $ev) {
            if ($event instanceof $ev) {
                $this->dispatcher->dispatch($ev, $event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the helper function `fire(Event $event)` looks like this:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Helpers\EventManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

if (!function_exists('fire')) {

    function fire(Event $event) {
        EventManager::getInstance()->fire($event);
    }

}
```

Thanks @Cerad for the heads-up.